# quad in a loop several times

Tags: matlab, math

```
I have a function as below
    function m=narkisos(a,b,c,x,y,z,t,rho)
    m=a.*x+b.*y-z+c*exp(t-rho)
    end
```

Then, in script I use:

```
    clear all;
    a=1;b=2;c=3;
    m=zeros(3,4,5,6);
    t=[1 2 3]'; z=[2 3 4 5]';
    for i=1:length(t)
    for j=1:length(z)
    for s=1:5
    for r=1:6
    f=@(rho)narkisos(a,b,c,s,r,z(j),t(i),rho);
             m(i,j,s,r)=quad(f,0,t(i));
    end
    end
    end
    end
```

After this part I need to use my narkisos again in another loops(more than 4) but for fixed indexes,example for s=2,r=3. Should I define another function in each loop or is there any way to call it? I don't like to write in each loop narkisos again, because that
reduce the speed of code.

```
for i=1:length(t)
    for j=1:length(z)

    **f=@(rho)narkisos(a,b,c,2,3,z(j),t(i),rho);**
             m(i,j,2,3)=quad(f,0,t(i));

    end
    end
```

Many thanks for any help,

Comment: Why the vote to close ?  This seems to reach the level of clarity of question that 50% of the questions around here reach.  With a little interpretation it's a reasonable, on-topic, programming-related question.

Comment: @ High Performance Mark, sorry Mark, but I'm afraid I didn't understand your interpretation. Did I close the vote option, some how?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you would like to [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoize)  calls to your function `narkisos`. It's not entirely straightforward, but I see that [Loren on the Art of Matlab](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/02/08/use-nested-functions-to-memoize-costly-functions/) has covered the topic.  If you are not already familiar with Loren's blog this is a good place to start, I've learned a lot from her over the years I've been using Matlab.